# RavenDB index creation error: index already exists

Tags: indexing, ravendb

I'm trying to play now with indexes creation for later use (for example for massive deletion using index) using RavenDb.

As far as I understand the best pratice is to create Indexes at the application start and there's no need to check if the index already exist as, in that case, it'll simply be updated (in case something have changed).

Given that I tried to build my own index in the global.asax application_start event (as I'm playing within an MVC application). Here's the code of my index creation:

```
store.DatabaseCommands.PutIndex("Xlns/ProductItems/ByCatalogueId",
      new IndexDefinitionBuilder<ProductItem>
          {
              Map = items => from product in items
                             select new
                                    {
                                       CatalogueId = product.CatalogueId
                                    }
           }
);
```

Pretty simple, isn't it?
Too bad when I first launch the application on an empty RavenDB, it doesn't raise any error (even if it seems that I can't use the index), and from the second time on, it gives me this error: `Cannot put index: Xlns/ProductItems/ByCatalogueId, index already exists`

The (not so) funny things is that I can't see the index anywhere using the RavenDB studio, and I'm not able to use it to query against. So it seems the index is not available but is somehow known by the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a suggestion: make your indexes be classes. That way you can strongly type your queries later on using the index type:

```
public class ProductItems_ByCatalogueId : AbstractIndexCreationTask<ProductItem>
{
    public ProductItems_ByCatalogueId()
    {
        Map = items => from product in items
                       select new
                       {
                           CatalogueId = product.CatalogueId
                       }
    }
}
```

Then, install all the indexes in your assembly using a single line of code:

```
// Inside Global.asax, inside .Initialize():
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(this.GetType().Assembly, store);
```

Now your index is ready to go. To query using this index:

```
var products = ravenSession.Query<ProductItem, ProductItems_ByCatalogueId>()
    .Where(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
    documentStore.DatabaseCommands.GetIndex("BlogPosts/ByTitles")
```

you can know if an index exist, then you know if you need to add it or not;
ravendb documentation reccomend to use classes to define static index: http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/client-api/querying/static-indexes/defining-static-index

The example of Judah Himango it's exactly (and correct) what you find in the link